# React-map-gl, React axios , React useEffect

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, react-hooks, axios

I am not able to fetch data using axios in the served page
from React App

Following Console error is received:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> AxiosErrorcode: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST"config: {transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}message: "Request failed with status code 404"name: "AxiosError"request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}response: {data: '\n\n\n<meta char…ody>\n
>
> ```
> Cannot GET /pins
> ```
>
> \n\n\n', status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}stack: "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404\n    at settle (http://localhost:3000/main.43eb08077ec519f83f4f.hot-update.js:14027:12)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (http://localhost:3000/main.43eb08077ec519f83f4f.hot-update.js:12722:66)"[[Prototype]]: Error

**App.js**

```
import React,{useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import Map, {Marker, Popup} from 'react-map-gl';
import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css';
import {Room,Star} from "@mui/icons-material";
import "./App.css"
import axios from 'axios';
// import {format}from 'timeago.js';
import timeago from 'javascript-time-ago';



function App(){
  const currentUser="Jane";
  const[pins,setPins]=useState([]);
  const[currentPlaceId,setCurrentPlaceId]=useState(null);
  const[newPlace,setnewPlace]=useState(null);
  const[title,setTitle]=useState(null);
  const[desc,setDesc]=useState(null);
  const[rating,setRating]=useState(0);


  const[viewport,setViewport]=useState({
    latitude:48.8584,
    longitude:2.2945,
    zoom:4,
  });


 
  //To get all the pins whenever refreshed  useEffect is used

  useEffect(()=>{
    const getPins=async()=>{
      try{

        const res=await axios.get("/pins");
        console.log(res.data);
        setPins(res.data);
      }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
      }
    };

    //Without calling function it is not going to work
    getPins();
  },[])
  //Handle Click at time of Choosing point

  const handleMarkerClick=(id,lat,long)=>{
    setCurrentPlaceId(id);
    setViewport({...viewport,latitude:lat,longitude:long})
  };

  const handleAddClick= (e)=>{
    const[longitude,latitude]=e.lngLat;
    setnewPlace({
      lat:latitude,
      long:longitude,
    });
  };


  const handleSubmit=async (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const newPin={
      username:currentUser,
      title,
      desc,
      lat:newPlace.lat,
      long:newPlace.long,

    }

    try{
      const res=await axios.post("/pins",newPin)
      setPins([...pins,res.data])
      setnewPlace(null)

    }catch(err)
    {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }


  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Map 
      {...viewport}
      style={{height:"100vh",width:"100vw"}}
      mapboxAccessToken={process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX}
      onMove={e=>setViewport(e.viewport)}
      mapStyle="mapbox://styles/safak/cknndpyfq268f17p53nmpwira"
      >
{/* //Since two or more components cannot be tracked simultaneously therefor using fragment */}
        {pins.map((p)=>(
          <>
          <Marker
          latitude={p.lat}
          longitude={p.long}
          offsetLeft={-20}
          offsetTop={-10}
          anchor="bottom"
          color="blue">

        <Room style={{
          fontSize:viewport.zoom*12,
          color:'slateblue', 
          cursor:"pointer",
        }}
        onClick={()=>handleMarkerClick(p._id)}
        />
        <div>You are Here</div>
        </Marker>
        {p._id===currentPlaceId &&(

          
          <Popup 
          latitude={p.lat} 
          longitude={p.long}
          anchor="left"
          closeButton={true}
          closeOnClick={false}
          onClose={()=>setCurrentPlaceId(null)}
          
          >
        <div className='card'>
        <label>Place</label>
        <label className='place'>
        <b>{p.title}</b>
        </label>
        <label>Review</label>
        <p className='desc'>{p.desc}</p>
        <label>Rating</label>
        <div className='star'>
        <Star className='star'/>
        <Star className='star'/>
        <Star className='star'/>
        <Star className='star'/>
        <Star className='star'/>
        </div>
        <label>Information</label>
        <span className="username">Created by <b>{p.username}</b></span>
        {/* <span className='date'>{format(p.createdAt)}</span> */}
        <span className="date">{timeago.format(Date.now() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)}</span>
        </div>
      </Popup>

        )}
</>
    ))}
        </Map>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "map",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.11",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.13",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.11.11",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "javascript-time-ago": "^2.5.9",
    "mapbox-gl": "^2.13.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-map-gl": "^7.0.21",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.9",
    "timeago.js": "^4.0.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },"proxy":"http://localhost:8800/api"
}
```

**Frontend**

**Index.js**

```
const express=require("express");
const mongoose=require("mongoose");
const dotenv=require("dotenv");
const pinRoute=require("./routes/pins");
const userRoute=require("./routes/users");


const app=express();

//Configuration
dotenv.config();
app.use(express.json());



// mongoose connection 
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL,{
    useNewUrlParser:true,
    useUnifiedTopology:true
}).then(()=>{
    console.log("MongoDB is connected");
}).catch((err)=>console.log(err));

//always before using app.listen
app.use("/api/users",userRoute);
app.use("/api/pins",pinRoute); // marked for check


// App listen
app.listen(8800,()=>{
    console.log("Backend Server is running");
})
```

**pins.js**  used for routing

```
const router=require("express").Router();
const Pin=require("../models/pin");


//Creating a Pin

router.post("/", async(req,res)=>{
    const newPin=new Pin(req.body)
    try{
        const savedPin= await newPin.save();
        res.status(200).json(savedPin);

    }catch(err)
    {
        res.status(500).json(err)
    }
})


//Getting all pins
router.get("/", async(req,res)=>{
    try{
        const pins=await Pin.find();
        res.status(200).json(pins);

    }catch(err){
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
})

module.exports=router;
```

I am expecting axios to fetch records from the backend server on development server using React app[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HR0PL.png).com/DHN9o.png)

Comment: "the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" usually means that the URL is broken, or that the resource doesn't exist anymore. React or Axios doesn't have anything to do with this.

Comment: I am using backend on same localhost therefore need proxy server

Comment: And I think that is not handled correctly

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).